# Delete a file in Android APP, but the file is still exist in MTP

Tags: android, mtp

I'm working on this these days...

My app delete somes files by itself. But when I connect my phone with PC by MTP mode, the files which have been delete are still 'alive', but cannot be copied or opened.

I know infact the files are already deleted, but I have to refresh MTP. I have tried the following method:

```
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(getApplicationContext(), paths, null, null);
```

but it doesn't work...

Does anybody here knows how to fix this issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you delete a file, Call refreshSystemMediaScanDataBase() method just after delete call trigger to refresh media

```
/** 
@param context : it is the reference where this method get called
@param docPath : absolute path of file for which broadcast will be send to refresh media database
**/
public static void refreshSystemMediaScanDataBase(Context context, String docPath){
   Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
   Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(docPath));
   mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
   context.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
}
```